# Extract Email Address from Thunderbird Emails

Tags: delphi

I want to extract all the email addresses found in a Thunderbird email file. Sometimes the emails are incased in spaces, sometimes in <> and possibly other ways. I'm able to find where a @ occurs on each string, but how do I grab the characters before and after it that form the email?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex was born for this kind of job. Here's a minimal console application that shows how you can use RegEx to extract all email addresses from one long block of text:

```
program Project25;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, PerlRegex;

var PR: TPerlRegEx;
    TestString: string;

begin

  // Initialize a test string to include some email addresses. This would normally
  // be your eMail text.
  TestString := '<one@server.domain.xy>, another@otherserver.xyz';

  PR := TPerlRegEx.Create;
  try
    PR.RegEx := '\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b'; // <-- this is the actual regex used.
    PR.Options := PR.Options + [preCaseLess];
    PR.Compile;
    PR.Subject := TestString; // <-- tell the TPerlRegEx where to look for matches
    if PR.Match then
    begin
      // At this point the first matched eMail address is already in MatchedText, we should grab it
      WriteLn(PR.MatchedText); // Extract first address (one@server.domain.xy)
      // Let the regex engine look for more matches in a loop:
      while PR.MatchAgain do
        WriteLn(PR.MatchedText); // Extract subsequent addresses (another@otherserver.xyz)
    end;
  finally PR.Free;
  end;

  Readln;
end.
```

See here for ways to get regular expressions for your older-then-XE version of Delphi:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html

Comment: @downvoter, why the downvote? Did you notice the *complete* console application showing the solution *in action*? If you did spot an error, would you mind sharing?

Comment: @Cosmin - maybe the downvoter doesn't like console applications :) I was that +1 anyway.

Comment: @daemon, I really hate downvotes without comments. Especially downvotes to straight-forward answers like this one, where there's little chance of error and no place for "differences of opinion".

Comment: What? Deleted my comment ponting to the major problem and now complaining about no explanation? Excellent staight-forward strategy, LOL.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a program that is doing that look for "Power Email Address Extractor and Validator".